# AMD Card on my 2015 iMac not detected

Tags: graphics, radeon

My iMac has an AMD Radeon R9 M395. I just installed elementary on it a few days ago. It's the first time I've installed Linux on it. As far as I can tell it's not detecting or using my graphics card. Is it supported? Is there anything I can do to get it to work?